How to extract segments and compute their length using ogr2ogr?
Given polygons like
$ cat a.csv                                                                                                       
WKT,Length                                                                                                        
"POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))",28 
...                                                                             

how can I extract each segment, and also compute its length, using ogr2ogr, ogrinfo, etc.? The output should look like:
$ ogr2ogr b.csv a.csv -dialect SQLite -sql what_goes_here?                                                                    
$ cat b.csv                                                                                                       
WKT,Length                                                                                                        
"LINESTRING (0 0, 5 0)",5                                                                                         
"LINESTRING (5 0, 5 9)",9                                                                                         
...                                                                                                               

Yes,

ST_DumpSegments DissolveSegments(),
ST_Length(), and
-explodecollections

look interesting. It's just hard to figure out how to string them all together.

Yes its possible as you suggested, just is necessary to create the appropriate query as
ogr2ogr b.csv a.csv -sql "SELECT MakeLine(ST_PointN(bds, value), ST_PointN(bds, \
value + 1)) WKT, ST_Length(MakeLine(ST_PointN(bds, value), ST_PointN(bds, value \
+ 1))) Length FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromText(WKT) geom, ST_Boundary(\
ST_GeomFromText(WKT)) bds, value FROM a, generate_series(1, (ST_NumPoints(\
ST_Boundary(ST_GeomFromText(WKT))) - 1)))" -dialect SQLite -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT

using the function generate_series to generate a sequence of numbers from 1 to n nodes - 1, then applies this series to create lines, using the N point of the boundary and N  + 1 to construct lines and calculate their lengths at the same time.
Resulting
$ cat b.csv                                                                                                                                             
WKT,Length
"LINESTRING(0 0, 5 0)",5
"LINESTRING(5 0, 5 9)",9
"LINESTRING(5 9, 0 9)",5
"LINESTRING(0 9, 0 0)",9

but there are additional steps to install and use the extension function generate_series with GDAL as follows
#download sqlite3 dev library to compile extensions
sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev

#create a dir to store SQLite extensions
mkdir -p /home/$USER/.sqlpkg
cd /home/$USER/.sqlpkg/

#download the series extension from GitHub official repository
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sqlite/sqlite/master/ext/misc/series.c

#compile the extension
gcc -g -fPIC -shared series.c -o series.so

#load the extension to use with GDAL/ORG
export OGR_SQLITE_LOAD_EXTENSIONS=/home/$USER/.sqlpkg/series


I am overjoyed that you all have solved this. But am flabbergasted at the amount of code needed. I kind of bet that by using an additional c.csv file, this whole thing could be whittled down to something that fits on the screen.

Also I tried this with slightly more input and ended up needing to kill(1) ogr2ogr as it was munching up CPU.

@DanJacobson answer edited to solve the problem of process hanging due to recursion.

For my mind ogr2ogr is not the right tool for this kind of advanded data processing and it would be better to hire someone to write a Python script that uses native GDAL functions.
That said, here comes an almost working ogrinfo example that splits a WKT geometry POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0)) into segments and computes their lengths. As a preraring step I used a the SpatiaLite function "NumGeometries" after "st_dissolvesegments" for checking the number of segments so I knew to select 4 subgeometries one by one. I think that nobody should try to use a command like this for doing anything serious. BTW I had to use / instead of " around the WKT part because otherwise the command line interpreter was not happy. That problem may be specific for Windows.
ogrinfo -sql "select '/'||st_astext( geometryn(st_dissolvesegments( st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))') ),1))||'/' as WKT, st_length( geometryn(st_dissolvesegments( st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))') ),1)) as length UNION ALL select '/'||st_astext( geometryn(st_dissolvesegments( st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))') ),2))||'/' as WKT, st_length( geometryn(st_dissolvesegments( st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))') ),2)) as length UNION ALL select '/'||st_astext( geometryn(st_dissolvesegments( st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))') ),3))||'/' as WKT, st_length( geometryn(st_dissolvesegments( st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))') ),3)) as length UNION ALL select '/'||st_astext( geometryn(st_dissolvesegments( st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))') ),4))||'/' as WKT, st_length( geometryn(st_dissolvesegments( st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))') ),4)) as length" :memory:
INFO: Open of `:memory:'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 4
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
WKT: String (0.0)
length: Real (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  WKT (String) = /LINESTRING(0 0, 5 0)/
  length (Real) = 5

OGRFeature(SELECT):1
  WKT (String) = /LINESTRING(5 0, 5 9)/
  length (Real) = 9

OGRFeature(SELECT):2
  WKT (String) = /LINESTRING(5 9, 0 9)/
  length (Real) = 5

OGRFeature(SELECT):3
  WKT (String) = /LINESTRING(0 9, 0 0)/
  length (Real) = 9


Cool! But I'm betting that perhaps via an extra c.csv file all this could get whittled down to something that fits on the screen...

Ho ho, it turns out to be a piece of cake, if we sit back and go in steps.
$ cat Makefile
BB = ogr2ogr -dialect SQLITE -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT $@ $<
FF = FROM "$(basename $<)"
mm.csv:ll.csv
    cat $<
    $(BB) \
    -sql 'SELECT (DissolveSegments(GEOMETRY)) AS WKT $(FF)'
    cat $@
nn.csv:mm.csv
    $(BB) \
    -explodecollections -sql 'SELECT GEOMETRY AS WKT $(FF)'
    cat $@
oo.csv:nn.csv
    $(BB) \
    -sql 'SELECT WKT, ST_Length(GEOMETRY) AS Length $(FF)'
    cat $@

OK, now let's let it rip!
$ make oo.csv
cat ll.csv
WKT
"POLYGON ((0 0,5 0,5 9,0 9,0 0))"
"POLYGON ((1 1,5 1,5 9,1 9,1 1))"
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLITE -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT mm.csv ll.csv \
-sql 'SELECT (DissolveSegments(GEOMETRY)) AS WKT FROM "ll"'
cat mm.csv
WKT
"MULTILINESTRING ((0 0,5 0),(5 0,5 9),(5 9,0 9),(0 9,0 0))"
"MULTILINESTRING ((1 1,5 1),(5 1,5 9),(5 9,1 9),(1 9,1 1))"
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLITE -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT nn.csv mm.csv \
-explodecollections -sql 'SELECT GEOMETRY AS WKT FROM "mm"'
cat nn.csv
WKT
"LINESTRING (0 0,5 0)"
"LINESTRING (5 0,5 9)"
"LINESTRING (5 9,0 9)"
"LINESTRING (0 9,0 0)"
"LINESTRING (1 1,5 1)"
"LINESTRING (5 1,5 9)"
"LINESTRING (5 9,1 9)"
"LINESTRING (1 9,1 1)"
ogr2ogr -dialect SQLITE -lco GEOMETRY=AS_WKT oo.csv nn.csv \
-sql 'SELECT WKT, ST_Length(GEOMETRY) AS Length FROM "nn"'
cat oo.csv
WKT,Length
"LINESTRING (0 0,5 0)",5
"LINESTRING (5 0,5 9)",9
"LINESTRING (5 9,0 9)",5
"LINESTRING (0 9,0 0)",9
"LINESTRING (1 1,5 1)",4
"LINESTRING (5 1,5 9)",8
"LINESTRING (5 9,1 9)",4
"LINESTRING (1 9,1 1)",8

Easy peasy. Also we observe no horizontal scrolling needed to read what I wrote!

It can be done without recursion (that is impractical for larger datasets) in one step, just it's necessary to add an extension with the SQLite function generate_series to replace that recursive CTE. I will add that to my answer later.
